# How to format columns so they line using ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, formatting

I have Ruby arrays inside an array that look like below:

More data info is here https://gist.github.com/theCrab/6064789

The column headers are **style**, **colour**, **size**, **desc**, **qty**, **min_qty**, **req_qty**, **root_sku**, **offset_size**

```
[
["UD/BOYS-TR/SENIOR/STANDARD", "*BLACK/2SHORT LEG", "28\" W", "29\"LEG STD MENS TROUSER", -10, 4, 14, "00001955", 1],
["UD/BOYS-TR/SENIOR/STANDARD", "*BLACK/2SHORT LEG", "30\" W", "29\"LEG STD MENS TROUSER", -14, 6, 20, "00001955", 2],
["UD/BOYS-TR/SENIOR/STANDARD", "*BLACK/2SHORT LEG", "32\" W", "29\"LEG STD MENS TROUSER", -29, 6, 35, "00001955", 3],
["UD/BOYS-TR/SENIOR/STANDARD", "*BLACK/3REG LEG", "28\" W", "31\"LEG STD MENS TROUSER", 0, 3, 3, "00001976", 1],
["UD/BOYS-TR/SENIOR/STANDARD", "*BLACK/3REG LEG", "30\" W", "31\"LEG STD MENS TROUSER", -12, 5, 17, "00001976", 2],
["UD/BOYS-TR/SENIOR/STANDARD", "*BLACK/3REG LEG", "32\" W", "31\"LEG STD MENS TROUSER", -6, 6, 12, "00001976", 3]
]
```

I want to print a nicely formated table that looks like below:

```
style | colour | size | desc | qty | min_qty | req_qty | root_sku
-----------------------------------------------------------------
standd| red    | 28 W | N/a  | 4   | 5       | 1       | 00001955
      |        | 30 W | N/a  | 9   | 5       | 4       | 00001955
      |        | 36 W | N/a  | 10  | 5       | 5       | 00001955
      | blue   | 28 W | N/a  | 4   | 5       | 1       | 00001955
      |        | 30 W | N/a  | 9   | 5       | 4       | 00001955
      |        | 36 W | N/a  | 10  | 5       | 5       | 00001955
fitted| red/blu| 28 W | N/a  | 4   | 5       | 1       | 00001954
      |        | 30 W | N/a  | 9   | 5       | 4       | 00001954
      |        | 36 W | N/a  | 10  | 5       | 5       | 00001954
      | blue   | 28 W | N/a  | 4   | 5       | 1       | 00001954
      |        | 30 W | N/a  | 9   | 5       | 4       | 00001954
      |        | 36 W | N/a  | 10  | 5       | 5       | 00001954
```

How can I best run through the Array and accomplish this feat?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There are a lot of gems for this task. You should search the web with `ruby gem print tables` or something similar...

Comment: Have you thought about dumping this data into a CSV? Here are [the docs for the CSV class in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

Comment: It seems like a lot of people are eager to down vote questions... There was a valid question here.

Comment: @GSP, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AGS, yes but 3 down votes to a new user with a new question? That seems like a bunch of bullies to a new user. One was enough to get the point across.

Comment: @GSP thanks for your support. @Romoku, I tried a lot of things except searching for a gem. @Batkins Am using `gem rdbi` to get this from a DBISAM database. I have had a long 2 weeks cracking other issues so i thought i could get help on this. Anyways thanks everyone.

Comment: @theCrab a couple of notes: 1. if you delete this question I think you get your points back (and/or a least get you the Disciplined badge), 2. consider resubmitting the question focusing on one part of the problem. e.g. is your primary problem with how to format columns so they line using ruby or is how to iterate through a nested array.  Good luck. Don't let this get you down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has a string formatting functionality that, I think, derives from the old C-style `sprintf` function. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf and http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-25

In the String class you use the `%` method and pass in an array.

```
outer_array.each do |inner_array|
  puts ('%6s|%8s|%5s|%6s|%4d|%8d|%6d|%10d' % inner_array)
end
```

(P.S. I just guessed on the formatting so you'll need to refine as necessary)